# duplicate entries in tableview

Tags: iphone

I have implemented the table view in my iphone app. In this I am using the date picker to put date entries in table view. But some time user by mistake set to put the entry which is already existing. How should I put the validation so that duplicate entry don't exist.

Please provide me some idea or solution.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding a new entry I would just take all the entries I have so far and put them in an `NSMutableSet` or `NSSet`

For example lets say all your elements are in the array myArray then:

```
NSSet* mySet;
[mySet addObjectsFromArray:myArray];
```

and then check the new Object with

```
if (![mySet containsObject: newObject]) {
   //do whatever you need to
} else {
//the object is already contained
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before refreshing tableview to display your new entry inserted, you should check your array from which you are populating your table. Try compare there & decide wether its already exists. if its is don't add. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this one; before reloading the table put this operation in your array

```
NSSet *uniqueNames = [NSSet setWithArray:HistoryArray];
    storyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[uniqueNames allObjects]];
```